# Sending only video out of HDMI cables – Mac OSX 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, audio, video, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a similar question to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/44924/send-only-video-out-with-hdmi-cable) but I'm on Mac OSX. I currently have a laptop, a second monitor (via HDMI), and a third monitor (via HDMI/thunderbolt adaptor). If I have sound playing, I only want it to come through my headphones. However, sometimes the sound will play through one of the monitors if the window playing the sound is on that monitor.

I tried going to "Sound" in System Preferences, but for both HDMI connections it says "The selected device has no output controls."

How can I change it so that audio does not get output via these HDMI cables? Alternatively, how can I change it so that if the headphones are plugged in, sound can *only* come out of the headphones?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default system audio output like this:  In the menu bar, option-click the volume icon, and choose headphones. This should affect most applications, but it's possible some apps or web plugins will have their own setting.